# Href="#" Don't Scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to JS - so just wondering whether you know how to solve this problem.

Current I have in my code

```
<a href='#' class="closeLink">close</a>
```

Which runs some JS to close a box. The problem I have is that when the user clicks on the link - the href="#" takes the user to the top of page when this happens.

How to solve this so it doesn't do this ? i.e. I cant use someting like onclick="return false" as I imagine that will stop the JS from working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to return false from your javascript click handler.  This will both prevent the event from bubbling up and cancel the normal action of the event.  It's been my experience that this is typically the behavior you want.

jQuery example:

```
$('.closeLink').click( function() {
      ...do the close action...
      return false;
});
```

If you want to simply prevent the normal action you can, instead, simply use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
$('.closeLink').click( function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     ... do the close action...
});
```

Comment: +1 - note if you're not using jQuery, make sure to check if window.event exists and if so, set window.event.returnValue = false before returning false - IE doesn't always stop bubbling unless you do this.

Comment: -1. While this works, `event.preventDefault` at the BEGINNING of the function is *the* correct way to do it.

Comment: @David - I've updated to note your comment.  My experience is that in almost all circumstances the behavior desired is to both cancel the normal action and prevent bubbling.  YMMV.

Comment: -1 retracted. :-) However, if you have an uncaught exception before the return false the link WILL be followed (or the #, in OP case).

Answer (score 48):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to just add another character after the pound symbol like this:

```
<a href='#a' class="closeLink">close</a>
```

Problem solved. Yes, it was that easy. Some may hate this answer, but they cannot deny that it works.

Just make sure you don't actually have a section assigned to "a" or it will go to that part of the page. (I don't see this as often as I use to, though) "#" by itself, by default, goes to the top of the page.

Comment: Feels like a hack, but is truly an easy fix.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: This solution has brought some elegant simplicity to my day. Thank you.

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: Love it. Nice and easy.

Answer (score 5):

***JavaScript version:***

```
myButton.onclick=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // code
    return false;
}
```

***jQuery version:***

```
$('.myButtonClass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // code
    return false;
});
```

This just do the job well! :)

Answer (score 5):

One option available to you is not to use `href = "#"`but instead `href = "javascript:;"` this will allow you to run the onclick handler whilst not scrolling.

For Example

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="doSomething()">Do Something</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

return false is the answer, but I usually do this instead:

```
$('.closeLink').click( function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      ...do the close action...
});
```

Stops the action from happening before you run your code.

Comment: `return false` works, but it isn't the answer in all cases.
`return false` calls both `event.preventDefault` AND `event.stopPropagation`. `stopPropagation` will prevent any other event attached to the object from firing. Which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems to be very popular, href='#' is not a magic keyword for JavaScript, it's just a regular link to an empty anchor and as such it's pretty pointless. You basically have two options:

1. Implement an alternative for JavaScript-unaware user agents, use the *href* parameter to point to it and cancel the link with JavaScript. E.g.:

   `<a href="close.php" onclick="close(); return false">`
2. When the *noscript* alternative is not available or relevant, you don't need a link at all:

   `<span onclick="close(); return false">Close</span>`

Comment: +1 for '#" is just an empty anchor without special meaning ... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like ROFLwTIME example, one easy way is put two ## in the href. It's not common, but worked for me.

```
  <a href='##' >close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is getting passed the eventObject you could use `preventDefault()`; returning false also helps.

```
mylink.onclick = function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 // stuff
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but nobody mentioned this.
Just make it `<a>Do Stuff</a>` without any `href` and add the style `cursor: pointer` to the element.
Then you can manage any click event with **jquery** as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Element").click(function(){
     alert("Hello");
    //Do Stuff
  })
});
```

```css
#Element {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#Element:hover {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="Element">Do Stuff</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use jQuery. That's so simple.

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
 if($(this).attr('href')=='#')
  return e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an a tag. Use a span with text that looks like a link. I usually create a "clickable" css class styled like links for this.

```
.closeLink {
    color: #4e73df;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
<span onClick="yourFunction()" class="clickable closeLink">close</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

*href='#/'* insted of href='#' works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap a div statement around a link, have the link return false, add the javascript functionality to the div on click...

```
<div onClick="javascript:close();">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;">Close</a>
</div>
```