# when clicking <a href="#"></a> don't want to go to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Href=“#” Don't Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255726/href-dont-scroll)

I have the following html in my code

`<a href="#">link</a>`

When i click on 'link', then my page goes automatically to top what is very normal as you all know. But i want that my page stays where it is when clicked on that link.

Somebody knows a good workaround for this?

PS: I can't change the html, it has to be a hyperlink

Thanks.

Comment: The entire point of `<a href="#">` is that it is a link to the top of the page! If you are abusing it as something to hang JavaScript off: don't. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Comment: If you don't want it to do what it's supposed to do in that setup, what _do_ you want it to do?  What is the purpose of this anchor tag?

Comment: We all are trying help you! You vote us down??????

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: Votes are anonymous.  Anybody could have voted the answers down.

Answer (score 14):

You can use like this `<a href="javascript:;">link</a>`

Comment: without checking,how you can put a minus for this?

Comment: It wasn't my vote, but I would agree with it that this isn't a "good" solution.  It's a workaround and seems to be a bit of a "hack" to me.

Comment: there's a difference between a working solution and a good solution, but I do agree, that the person put the minus should have a comment to explain why.

Comment: i try already this one in one of my application.thats why i place this one.

Comment: its a hack, but it **works**.

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the a tag, you can put :

```
<a href="#stay_here" name="stay_here">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can change the html if you apply `cursor:pointer` (from CSS) on it.
For your problem, you need `event.returnValue = false;` in ie and `event.preventDefault();` for the browsers.

See this too: [Href="#" Don't Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255726/href-dont-scroll)