# when clicking on image href=# it scrolls to the top

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the code I am using for my site
Each image link is set up to advance to the next image when clicked
The problem is that when I click on the image the page scrolls back to the top. I want this to stop

I've used the return false tag on the onclick tag but then when the image is clicked it continuously scrolls through the array of images.

Any solutions? Below is my code

```
<script language="JavaScript">

  <!-- -->


var interval = 1500;
var random_display = 0;
var imageDir = "imgs/";

var imageNum = 0;
imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "1.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "2.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "3.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "4.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "5.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "6.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "7.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "8.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "9.jpg");
imageArray[imageNum++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "10.jpg");

var imageNumTwo = 0;
imageArrayTwo = new Array();
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t1.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t2.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t3.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t4.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t5.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t6.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t7.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t8.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t9.jpg");
imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "t10.jpg"); 

var imageNumThree = 0;
imageArrayThree = new Array();
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th1.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th2.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th3.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th4.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th5.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th6.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th7.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th8.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th9.jpg");
imageArrayThree[imageNumThree++] = new imageItem(imageDir + "th10.jpg");    


var totalImages = imageArray.length;
var totalImagesTwo = imageArrayTwo.length;
var totalImagesThree = imageArrayThree.length;

function imageItem(image_location) {
    this.image_item = new Image();
    this.image_item.src = image_location;
}
function get_ImageItemLocation(imageObj) {
    return(imageObj.image_item.src)
}


function randNum(x, y) {
    var range = y - x + 1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + x;
}

function getNextImage() {
    if (random_display) {
        imageNum = randNum(0, totalImages-1);
    }
    else {
        imageNum = (imageNum+1) % totalImages;
    }   

    var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(imageArray[imageNum]);
return(new_image);
}


function getNextImageTwo() {
    if (random_display) {
        imageNumTwo = randNum(0, totalImagesTwo-1);
    }
    else {
        imageNumTwo = (imageNumTwo+1) % totalImagesTwo;
    }   

    var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(imageArrayTwo[imageNumTwo]);
return(new_image);
}


function getNextImageThree() {
    if (random_display) {
        imageNumThree = randNum(0, totalImagesTwo-1);
    }
    else {
        imageNumThree = (imageNumThree+1) % totalImagesThree;
    }   

    var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(imageArrayThree[imageNumThree]);
return(new_image);
}


function prevImage(place) {
    var new_image = getPrevImage();
    document[place].src = new_image;
}

function switchImage(place) {
    var new_image = getNextImage();
    document[place].src = new_image;
    var recur_call = "switchImage('"+place+"')";
    timerID = setTimeout(recur_call, interval);
    }

function switchImageTwo(place) {
    var new_image = getNextImageTwo();
    document[place].src = new_image;
    var recur_call = "switchImageTwo('"+place+"')";
    timerID = setTimeout(recur_call, interval);
    }


function switchImageThree(place) {
    var new_image = getNextImageThree();
    document[place].src = new_image;
    var recur_call = "switchImageThree('"+place+"')";
    timerID = setTimeout(recur_call, interval);
    }


</script>




  </head>

<body>


<div id="content">
<div id="title"><a href="mailto:hello@a.com"><center><img src="imgs/adil.gif" alt="A D I L" width="293" height="115" border="0"></center></a></div>
<div id="books">
  <p><a href="#" onclick="switchImage('slideImg'); clearTimeout(timerID)"><img src="imgs/1.jpg" name="slideImg" width="300" height="427" border="0"></a>
  <img src="imgs/px.gif" width="40">
  <a href="#" onclick="switchImageTwo('slideImg2'); clearTimeout(timerID)"><img src="imgs/t1.jpg" name="slideImg2" width="300" height="423" border="0"></a>
  <img src="imgs/px.gif" width="40">
  <a href="#" onclick="switchImageThree('slideImg3'); clearTimeout(timerID)"><img src="imgs/th1.jpg" name="slideImg3" width="300" height="427" border="0"></a>
  <img src="imgs/px.gif" width="993" height="40"></p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Array_literals

Comment: possible duplicate of [Href="#" Don't Scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255726/href-dont-scroll)

Comment: Completely away from your question - why do you have 30 near-identical assignment lines.  Why don't you assign them via one or more `for` loops?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to return false from whatever function is called by your click handler.

Comment: I've done that. It helped to stop the scrolling to the top but then a new problem arised. That problem was that the images in the array kept switching without being clicked

Comment: You should look for an issue to the fundamental problem in your code that causes the constant image switching then - including the way your click handler is setup would help.  You might try using preventDefault instead of returning false (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:event.preventDefault) as well.