PHP HTML JS pagination
I have a page which feedbacks which looks like this (I just show 1 comment per page to see if the pagination works fine. Otherwise I'll show more):

The feedbacks come from a mysql database and are filtered as 1 feedback per page at the moment.
In my code, I put the logics so that when I click on the next page, it shows the comments correctly with the GET feature which is sent back from a PHP function in another file.
Here is a small code sample:
In my main file I call a function called paginate and I print it out
<?php  print paginate('', '?courseid='.$courseid.'&page=', $nbrPages, $current); ?>

In my main function in another file I have something like this which constructs the pagination with PHP variables, one by one.
function paginate($url, $link, $total, $current, $adj=5){ 
    $prev = $current - 1; 
    $next = $current + 1;
    $penultimate = $total - 1; 
    $pagination = '';
    if ($total > 1) {
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"row pagination_row\">\n";
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"col\">\n"; 
..

The problem I am facing is: When I click on "next" or any page I want to go, there is this this refresh feature which scrolls to the top and the user has to scroll back down to see the comment. So I put this code in javascript to rescroll back to the comment:
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        
        var scrollpos = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
        if (scrollpos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
            sessionStorage.removeItem('scrollpos');
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
    });
</script>

If works fine but There's a micro-freeze every time, which makes sense because the standard behavior is to scroll up after a refresh, and the script here scrolls down again. I've also seen this JQuery class preventDefault(); which prevents the page to scroll at all but in my case nothing refreshes. Does anyone have an idea how to refresh and not make the scroll up and scroll down action? So it seems more smooth? Thanks

We need more context; where do you see preventDefault();? What should trigger the refresh?

Instead of using Javascript to scroll maybe consider using anchor on the element you want to scroll to. So add an id to the html element you want to scroll to, then add # at the back of the pagination link. e.g. ?courseid='.$courseid.'&page=1#id-of-the-element'. This might help https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Hi Mykaf. I was talking about other threads that i've seen, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255726/href-dont-scroll. But I did not implement it in this example. I hope this helps. If you need more context, I can certainly provide you with more.

Thanks Morgan, Ill try this. Greetings :)

"but in my case nothing refreshes."; where are you hoping to see a refresh? What event should trigger this?

Oh sorry. Yes I tried a prevent default method like this:
PHP File:
$pagination .= "<a class='paginate' href="{$url}{$link}{$prev}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true">";
Main File
 But it did not refresh the main elements I expected.
You created an anchor tag, which should navigate to the specified url, and then added a click event to to the anchor tag that prevents the default behavior (of navigating to the specified link). How is that supposed to refresh anything?

Yes I just did now, but I wasn't talking about this in the main question. I was talking about how to make it as smooth as possible when I change the view of the feedbacks. But nevermind, the anchor tag is not a bad idea anyway, it works perfectly fine. I'll use Morgan's suggestion. Thanks for your help

Instead of printing your comments out via PHP, consider using the JS fetch API to fetch comment data on the fly from a PHP file hosted on your server. This will prevent your page refreshing as only a few elements will be updated rather than refreshing the whole DOM. Your PHP backend file should return JSON formatted data that JS can interpret and load.
Security Side Note: Ensure to escape any malicious HTML code that may be in your comment data using the PHP function htmlspecialchars()

I solved it with Anchor tags (Thanks to morgan9999's suggestion):
I make a div with any id:
<div id="anchor">
..My code..
</div>

in my php file I add the anchors like this:
$pagination .= "<li><a class='paginate' href=\"{$url}{$link}{$i}#anchor\">{$i}</a></li>";

and it goes not completely up, until the div with the id, and it still makes some small artefacts but it's ok.
